# Почему запустив сервер Django с помощью Docker, он не работает?

Tags: django, docker

Я только начал изучать docker и столкнулся с такой проблемой, что сделав dockerfile и compose, успешно все запустил, но сам сервер не отвечает((

**dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.8

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /code

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver"]
```

**docker-compose**

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  django:
    image: django-docker:0.0.1
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

**Ошибка сайта**

```
 Страница недоступна Сайт 127.0.0.1 не отправил данных.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте запуститься так:

```
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```